# On/Off time(datetime field) doesn't cleared after cancel button is pressed

Tags: extjs, widget, aem

I open page properties and fill some fields

[image: filled properties]

After I pressed cancel button, and reopened properties dialog, all field cleared, but datetime fields didn't.

[image: reopend dialog]

What is the rigth way to clear datetime fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was debuggin and find out strange behavior of  isApplyDefault method in `\ibs\cq\ui\widgets\source\ext\override\widgets\form\Field.js`. It is compare created and modefied date, if they equals returns true, otherwise false.

I just ovveride method processRecord in DateTime.js to remove calling isApplyDefault:

```
processRecord: function(record, path) {
    if (this.fireEvent('beforeloadcontent', this, record, path) !== false) {
        var v = record.get(this.getName());
        if (v == undefined && this.defaultValue != null) {
               this.setValue(this.defaultValue);
        }
        else {
            this.setValue(v);
        }
        this.fireEvent('loadcontent', this, record, path);
    }
}
```

in Field.js it is:

```
processRecord: function(record, path) {
    if (this.fireEvent('beforeloadcontent', this, record, path) !== false) {
        var v = record.get(this.getName());
        if (v == undefined && this.defaultValue != null) {
            if (this.isApplyDefault(record, path)) {
               this.setValue(this.defaultValue);
            }
        }
        else {
            this.setValue(v);
        }
        this.fireEvent('loadcontent', this, record, path);
    }
}
```

See also in  [adobe forum](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__ayyu-i_open_pageproperti.html#forum__ayyu-i_open_pageproperti__9utx-i_was_debugginandf)